# .NET Core - IAuthorizationFilter not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I try to create a filter with .NET Core 3.1

for some weird reason, many things cannot be found

**The type or namespace name 'FilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

first, System.Web.Mvc could not be found, so I uninstalled, reinstalled the microsoft apsnet mvc package

but I still get the same issue

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyApp.Filters
{
    public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for helping me on this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently the examples I found are not .NET Core (???)

I found another doc from Microsoft that says to use IAsyncPageFilter, IOrderedFilter instead

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand how ASP.NET Core works. There is no `System.Web.Mvc.Filters` namespace and no `FilterAttribute`; any MVC-related packages relate to legacy ASP.NET and are therefore incompatible with Core (hence why you cannot use that namespace), so there's no point in installing them.

If you have an ASP.NET MVC application and you want to upgrade it to Core, [you should read the document that Microsoft has prepared for exactly that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: I am just following a tutorial and it's a .NET Core tutorial...I did not even say anything about an upgrade

Comment: the doc does not even address the subject of the question

Comment: the whole idea is to check if I have a field present in the request (with a particular value) ...the examples here are really overkill and complicated just to do that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Then the tutorial you are following is either completely wrong or completely out of date. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iauthorizationservice